# Spotify, Youtube, Shockwave Flash, and other programs not working

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, flash, youtube, spotify

When I open spotify it will continuously load or if it stops i cannot play a song, also on Youtube i can click on a video from the homepage but the video will not load and i cannot click on anything. Other video sites will also crash and i get the "shockwave has stopped working" popup. Even Windows Media Player, skype, and steam don't work. I have updated countless things, restarted multiple times, and checked for viruses and have gotten no change. Is there anything I should do or do i need to just reboot to an earlier date? Sometimes Youtube will work for one video then no longer work at all.

I have done a spybot search and an avast search and neither came up with anything. I also don't believe i have any refresh dates for my computer so I want to use that as a last choice.

Comment: What OS? RAM? HDD?

Comment: OS- windows 8.1, RAM- 6gb HDD-317gb free/676gb

Comment: i believe this has something to do with my sound card because when i try to do anything that involves sound that program/site crashes. hope this helps

Comment: Then, did you tried to update/repair your sound card driver ?

Comment: Also, are you connecting through a corporate/company network ? Maybe a proxy server prevents accessing such services.

Comment: I updated my drivers very recently but i will check again. I am on a personal laptop that's not connected to any network besides my wifi

Comment: I think I have found the source of the problem and that is spotify. When i went on youtube the day after this problem occurred it worked fine but as soon as i opened Spotify there was no sound and youtube would no longer work. i restarted and youtube worked fine. Please tell me if this could actually be what the problem is.

Comment: in response to my previous comment i would have to say that it is not spotify and i am stuck again. after i clicked on another video on youtube it stopped working and windows media player is also not working and on other sites i get the shockwave has stopped working pop0up. please help

Comment: Its sounds more like adware/spyware that trying to inject things in media objects (plugins, html5 object, ect). All the programs you describe are using the browser or some part of it.. Maybe scan the register and malicious plugins with http://www.yac.mx . And you can try to reinstall flash.

Comment: do you think that it could have infected my headset or other usb connected device because when not connected to anything my laptop has been able to play videos (only tested on youtube) perfectly fine. if so how would i get rid of those?